# So how is it that Voldemort didn't know the rules of Wand allegiance

Tags: harry-potter

Draco disarmed Dumbledore before Snape killed him, so the wand allegiance had already passed to Draco. Yet Voldemort still killed Snape to obtain the Elder Wand's allegiance.

Surely if you knew magic as well as he did you would know that its not who killed the wizard that becomes the new owner of the wand its actually the person who disarms them?

Comment: I don't think "legency" is a word, and all the dictionaries I checked agree. What meaning did you intend to convey with "legency"?

Comment: Also, your question is based on a false premise: the Elder Wand **will** accept as its master the person who killed its previous master. It will also accept as its master the person who disarmed, incapacitated, or otherwise defeated its previous master. What Voldemort got wrong was misidentifying said previous master.

Comment: Voldemort did not know the rules of wand legency because even Voldemort does not know everything

Comment: Rmember that the concept of the Elder Wand is new to Voldemort

Comment: @Martha Must mean allegiance? Based on the context that's certainly one way of putting it and is the closest word I can think of.

Answer (score 9):

Voldemort clearly does understand the rules of Wand Allegiance as he killed Snape specifically to take control of the Elder Wand, he just wasn't aware that Draco Malfoy had disarmed Dumbledore before Snape killed him.

As to why Snape didn't tell him this, we can't be sure but maybe he just didn't want to indirectly kill Draco by telling Voldemort this.

Comment: Yes! .. Voldy was not aware what happened in Hogwarts Tower.

Comment: Voldemort would have definitely known what happened at the tower, as even if Snape withheld information, Bellatrix would certainly have left nothing out. I would expect she would have claimed to have helped seal the deal with the unbreakable vow.

Anyway, the point being that "defeat" could only possibly be interpreted by Voldemort as "kill". He would never ever consider disarming a defeat. If he knew the Elder Wand counted that as a defeat, there would have been no reason for him to kill Snape outright (and lose what he thought was one of his own) when a simple stun would have worked.

Comment: It doesn't matter if Voldemort knew Draco disarmed Dumbledore. He believed you could get ownership of the Elder Wand by killing the previous owner. Since Snape was the one who killed Dumbledore Voldemort would have gone after Snape anyway. And there's no reason for Snape to hide the fact that Draco disarmed him (even if the topic did come up at all) just to protect him from Voldemort, because Snape doesn't even know about the existence of the Elder Wand.

Comment: @Applekid He disarmed Dumbledore before the others arrived. And Bellatrix wasn't there; that was a film invention.

Answer (score 6):

As is stated multiple times throughout the books, there are many types of magic that Voldemort completely ignores because he doesn't happen to think they're worthwhile.

Answer (score 1):

Killing a wizard does take ownership of his wand, but the reason the Elder Wand didn't become his after killing Snape, is that it was never Snape's wand. If Snape had killed Dumbledore before Draco disarmed him, he would be the master of the Elder Wand. Wands change their allegiance after death or disarming, I think. Again, I don't have the books with me here to check (maybe I should stop answering your questions until I do then :p).

Comment: Not sure if it ownership would have been transferred: it wasn't a true defeat; Dumbledore planned it. Dumbledore at least believed that it would make the Elder Wand have no power. And Harry asks the portrait after Voldemort is defeated finally and he agrees: Harry asks if if he's not disarmed and dies with mastery of the Elder Wand will the wand's power die.